# Selenium2 phpunit submit form wait for page to load

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a test where a blank form is submitted, wait for 10 seconds to ensure the page has reloaded and then check that the error messages are appearing.

I'm using Selenium2 which I start with

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
```

I have some tests that make sure the fields are present e.g.

```
public function testEmailFieldIsPresentById()
{
$element = $this->byCssSelector('#email');
$this->assertEquals(1, count($element));
}
```

I have tried different function calls based on different articles I have read but neither are working.

This is what I have so far with the two attempts to wait commented out.

```
<?php

class LoginFormSubmitTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/login');
    }

    public function testWithAllBlankFields()
    {
        // Submit the form
        $this->byId('recording-form-login')->submit();
        // Wait 10 seconds
        //$this->waitForPageToLoad(10000);
        //$this->timeouts()->implicitWait(10000);
    }

}
```

Can anyone point me to some good documentation on this suggest a way to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
$this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/login');
```

does not actually open the web page. setBrowserUrl == Set the **base** URL for the tests.

This should work for you - note the extra line **$this->url('http://localhost/login');**

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/');
}

public function testWithAllBlankFields()
{
    $this->url('http://localhost/login');
    // Submit the form
    $this->byId('recording-form-login')->submit();
    // Wait 10 seconds
    //$this->waitForPageToLoad(10000);
    //$this->timeouts()->implicitWait(10000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found two good tutorials which explain that what is needed is a a wrapper for the Selenium API for PHP to interact with.

http://testigniter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/running-selenium-2-webdriver-using.html
http://edvanbeinum.com/using-selenium-2-phpunit-to-automate-browser-testing

After downloading the wrapper from https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver my code now looks like the following and captures a screenshot on failure in the tearDown function

```
<?php

// Include the Facebook PHP Webdriver init file
require_once '../php-webdriver/__init__.php';

class loginFormSubmitTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
    * @var WebDriverSession
    */
    protected $_session;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $web_driver = new WebDriver();
        $this->_session = $web_driver->session();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {

        // Get the status of the test
        $status = $this->getStatus();

        // Check if the status has an error or a failure
        if ($status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_ERROR || $status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_FAILURE) {
            // Take a screenshot
            $image_data = base64_decode($this->_session->screenshot());

            file_put_contents(date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.png', $image_data);
        }

        $this->_session->close();
        unset($this->_session);
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function test_submit_form_with_all_blank_fields()
    {

        $this->_session->open('http://localhost/login');

        $this->_session->element(
            'id',
            'recording_form_login_submit'
        )->click();

        $email_label_span_text = $this->_session->element('css selector', '#recording-form-login label[for="email"] span')->text();

        $this->assertSame(
            'Required',
            $email_label_span_text
        );

    }

}
```

Comment: Your open method here is the Selenium 1 equivalent to the url method in Selenium 2